# Click Event is not fired (or ignored) when performing an ajax call in the background that validates a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-events

I am validating an objects "name" to ensure it is unique. To perform this I am using the jQuery bassisstance validation plugin. I issue a SYNCHRONOUS ajax call during the validation method to verify uniqueness as follows

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("new_user_role_name_unique", function(value) {
    var role_name_valid = true;
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        data: "name=" + encodeURIComponent(value),
        url: '/user_roles/0/name_taken',
        success: function (result) {
            var taken = JSON.parse(result);
            role_name_valid = !taken
        }
    });
    return role_name_valid;
}, I18n.t('user_role_name_already_used'));
```

When I type a name in the "name" text field and then immediately click on the submit button defined below, I would expect the method `addUserRole` to be called:

```
      <button id='user_role_add_button' class='rounded green' type='button' onclick="addUserRole()" name='add' value='add'>
         <span><%= t(:user_role_add_button) %></span>
      </button>
```

However, the method `addUserRole` is not called. If I type a "name" however and then lose focus on the name text field, prior to clicking the button the method is called with no drama.

So in essence, my problem is when the name textfield has focus, I have to double click the save button to ensure `addUserRole` method is called.

Does anyone know why my click event seems to be lost on the first click under these circumstances, but not the second? I cant have the user double click on the button to save.

Comment: `async:false,` there is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronous ajax calls block UI events and you may lose some events when doing that.  It would be much better to use an async ajax call and let the user events happen in real-time.

Without the actual relevant HTML from your page and all participating event handlers, it's hard to follow the sequence you are describing to offer more info.

Comment: Thank you. You have answered the question as to why I am losing the click event. The only problem is the ajax call resolves the uniqueness validation. Making async true can return an inaccurate validation result.

Comment: Making the ajax call async will not return an inaccurate result - the ajax call returns the same result either way.  You will have to restructure your code a bit to use an async call, but it's a much, much, much better user experience.